# Default SA password of SQL Server automatically installed by SharePoint Server 2010 setup

Tags: passwords, sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I installed SharePoint server 2010 recently on a test server. It was installed in `standalone mode`.

After the installation, I realized that it had installed `SQL Server Express 2008` (`10.0.2531.0`) automatically as well.

**I need to know the password for the `sa` user of this SQL server instance that it automatically installed. (I was not prompted for a password during the SharePoint installation)**

Reason that I need the sa password of the SharePoint SQL instance:

SharePoint is working without any issues. However, I need to create a new login on the SQL server and give it permissions to some of the databases.

I can login to the SQL server using Windows Authentication. However, using this login, I do not have permissions to create a new login.

I need to create a new login in order to complete the steps mentioned here:
http://www.sharepointassist.com/2010/01/29/the-local-farm-is-not-accessible-cmdlets-with-featuredependencyid-are-not-registered/comment-page-1/#comment-1566

Comment: I think if its 2008 R2, sa is disabled by default. All you need to do is enable the sa account and set a new password. Obviously you will need to use a windows admin account for this.

Comment: You can also look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781365/how-to-change-sa-password-in-sql-server-2008-express

Comment: @Steve Thanks. The `sa` login appears to be disabled. However, it does not allow me to enable it when logged in with the Windows account that I used while installing SharePoint.

Comment: I still think you need to have a computer administrator role for this, if this is not possible then you should get someone who is to enable the sa account.

Comment: @Steve Thanks. I will check this and let you know!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here are the steps I did to fix this:

- Login to the SQL Server using a **local** account which has **administrative privileges** account (eg: .\Administrator)
- Once you have logged into Windows, open SQL Management Studio
- Connect to the SharePoint SQL instance using `Windows Authentication`
- Enable Mixed Mode Authentication (this is not enabled by default for the SharePoint SQL instance)
- Set a password for the `sa` account
- Enable the `sa` account
- Restart the SQL instance (required due to change in authentication mode)

**Enabling Mixed Mode Authentication:**

1. Right click on the SQL server instance
2. Click on `Properties`
3. Click on `Security` on the left pane
4. Click on SQL Server and `Windows Authentication Mode` under the `Server authentication` section

You can also use the following SQL query to do the same:

```
EXEC xp_instance_regwrite N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 
    N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'LoginMode', REG_DWORD, 2
```

[Note: `2` indicates mixed mode authentication. `1` is for windows only authentication]

**Setting a password on the `sa` account:**

1. Under the SQL instance, expand `Security` and `Logins`
2. Right click on `sa` and click on `Properties`
3. Type the new password in the `Password` and `Confirm Password` boxes

You can also use the following SQL query to do the same:

```
ALTER LOGIN [sa] WITH PASSWORD='newpassword', CHECK_POLICY=OFF
```

[Note: `CHECK_POLICY=OFF` ensures that Windows password policies of the computer on which SQL Server is running will NOT be enforced on this login]

**Enabling the `sa` account:**

1. Under the SQL instance, expand `Security` and `Logins`
2. Right click on `sa` and click on `Properties`
3. Click on `Status` on the left pane
4. Click on `Enabled` under the `Login` section

You can also use the following SQL query to do the same:

```
ALTER LOGIN [sa] ENABLE
```

Comment: Cool answer. It works like a charm.

Comment: There is only two users for my DB, my admin account on windows and SA account. And guess what, my admin account does not have permission to enable the SA account. Awesome! they essential set me up with a DB I have little permissions over and can not remove. If i try to create another user, what do you know I don't have permission.

God I hate microsoft sometimes :P